# List comprehension : Double loop WITH conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization, list-comprehension

I try to train myself since some days on lists comprehension in Python 3 and I have an issue.
I saw in others topics double loops syntax but never with condition on the 2nd loop.

So, I have to say if I can charge or not a sample among sample values and maximum capacity.

I have a dictionary *samples* who contains id of sample with its A/B/C values.
I have a dict *maximum* who is max capacity I can charge.
And a *samples_to_check* list with samples that I have to return an answer.

```
samples_to_check = [0, 1, 2]

samples = {0: {"A": 2, "B": 0, "C": 3},
           1: {"A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 2},
           2: {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 5},
           3: {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 2}}

maximum = {"A": 2, "B": 2, "C": 2}
```

In this example, we can only charge the sample 1 because A,B and C <= 2
I succeeded to resolve it with this solution :

```
result2 = [
    "CHARGE " + str(sample_id) for sample_id in samples_to_check
    if maximum["A"] - samples[sample_id]["A"] >= 0 and maximum["B"] - samples[sample_id]["B"] >= 0 and maximum["C"] - samples[sample_id]["C"] >= 0
]

print(result2)
['CHARGE 1']
```

But I would like to know if a best solution is possible without repeat the same condition for each letter.

I tried this one but its doesn't work.

```
result = [
    "CHARGE " + str(sample_id) for sample_id in samples_to_check
    for letter in ["A", "B", "C"] if maximum[letter] - samples[sample_id][letter] >= 0
]

print(result)
['CHARGE 0', 'CHARGE 0', 'CHARGE 1', 'CHARGE 1', 'CHARGE 1', 'CHARGE 2', 'CHARGE 2']
```

Thanks.

Comment: The "correct" form is ``... if any(maximum[letter] - samples[sample_id][letter] >= 0
for letter in ["A", "B", "C"]])`` but frankly neither is particularly readable. A regular ``for`` loop or a function for the condition might be better than cramming everything into one expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all/any function to check this condition for all letters:

```
["charge {}".format(sample_id) for sample_id in samples_to_check if 
 all(maximum[key] - val >= 0  for key, val in samples[sample_id].items())]
```

but it is less readable than normal for loop which I recommend.

```
for sample_id in samples_to_check:
    if all(maximum[key] - val >= 0  for key, val in samples[sample_id].items()):
        print('sample_id:', sample_id)
```

Comment: Note that ``any``/``all`` generally work better with a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, since that allows to bail out early instead of creating all results and then discarding some. ``maximum[key] - val >= 0`` could also be (better?) written as just ``maximum[key] >= val``.

Comment: yes of course! You are 100% right about generator! I don't even know why I put there a list. About condition - I wanted to left it as OP.

Comment: @Relandom recommended to use f-strings now in Python. `f"charge {sample_id}"`

Comment: @blueteeth Yes, but OP didn't specify which version of python is using.

Comment: Thank you very much, excatly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar to @Relandom but formatted slightly different. I think list comprehensions are much neater than a regular for loop and create much more pythonic code.

In this rather than looping through `samples_to_check`, I'm looping through the main data, and then checking if the sample_id *is* something to check, which makes more sense to me.

```py
[
    f"CHARGE {sample_id}"
    for sample_id, sample in samples.items()
    if (
        sample_id in samples_to_check
        and all(maximum[key] >= val for key, val in sample.items())
    )
]
```

Comment: This is an extremely wasteful approach – it has O(nm) versus the initial O(m) runtime complexity. It will needlessly look at ``samples`` that are not relevant, and will over and over again look through all items in ``samples_to_check`` to see if ``sample_id`` is in there.

Comment: I see your point. Not exactly *extremely* wasteful though, especially not at this size. You can make `samples_to_check` a set.